# My function on VBA does give some false negative output

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Recently, I wrote a code in order to check the Social Insurance Number issued in Germany.
I have 3 outputs: surname, dob and the given Social Insurance Number. Between 3rd and 8th digits it consists of date month and last two years of birth.
However, in some cases, it does return false negative. Can anyone suggest any improvements? I am very new to VBA and coding in general, that's why feel free to check and suggest any improvements.
I will post my code, an example where it gives true positive and examples where it does give false negatives.

__Steinbach 01.12.1991  12011291S533

false negative results for

Akyol       31.10.1993 13311093A017__
Voormann    22.11.1995 53221195V018__
Köhler      15.10.1997 14151097K056__
Xheladini   22.10.1991 65221091X509__

The function in Visual Basic

```
Public Function firstDigitsSocIn(surname As String, dob As Date, socialSecurityNumber As String) As String
        'defining variables (add gender after surname when data is available)

        Dim dayOfMonth As Integer
        Dim monthSoc As Integer
        Dim yearSoc As Integer
        Dim firstCharSurname As String
        Dim customMadeNumber As String
        'Dim genderCode As Integer            enable when having genders in data set
        'Dim genderCheck As Boolean
        Dim resultFirst7Chars As Boolean
        Dim resultInclGenderCheck As Boolean
        Dim resultFinal As Boolean
        'setting up variables with correct values

        dayOfMonth = Day(dob)
        monthSoc = Month(dob)
        yearSoc = Right(Year(dob), 2)
        firstCharSurname = Left(surname, 1)
        'genderCode = Left(Right(socialSecurityNumber, 3), 2)


        'if gender = "M" am

        'custommadenumber is composed using the credentials of the user
        customMadeNumber = dayOfMonth & monthSoc & yearSoc & firstCharSurname

        resultFirst7Chars = StrComp(Mid(socialSecurityNumber, 3, 7), customMadeNumber, vbBinaryCompare)

        'If gender = "M" And genderCode < 50 Then
        'genderCheck = True
        'ElseIf gender = "F" And genderCode > 50 Then
        'genderCheck = True
        'Else
        'genderCheck = False
        'End If

        'resultInclGenderCheck = resultFirst7Chars And genderCheck

        'resultFinal = resultInclGenderCheck And True 'put Pruefziffer check here as well

        firstDigitsSocIn = resultFirst7Chars

End Function
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use `StrComp` instead of `=`? (I would guess that you only want a `True`/`False` value). Am I correct to assume that you want the function to return true for all your examples?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct, I wanted to use 'StrComp' to check the exact match, however I forgot to follow the structure '(StrComp(Str1, Str2, vbTextCompare) = 0)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two severe problems.

1. You build your custom number with `Integer`s instead of strings. That means that numbers less that 10 will lose their leading 0.
2. You use `StrComp` when you actually only want to check if strings are equal. That wouldn't be too bad but you are casting the result as `Boolean` (because `resultFirst7Chars` is a boolean). `StrComp` returns 0 if the strings are equal and -1 or +1 otherwise. But when you case 0, -1 and 1 as booleans you get `False`, `True`, and `True`, the exact opposite of what you want!

Prakash alreadygave a solution to the second problem. Another would be to just use

```
resultFirst7Chars = (socialSecurityNumber = customMadeNumber)
```

**Edit**: Since Prakash deleted his answer here is what he suggested:

```
resultFirst7Chars = (StrComp(Mid(socialSecurityNumber, 3, 7), customMadeNumber, vbBinaryCompare) = 0)
```

i.e. checking if `StrComp` returned 0 or not.

---

For the first problem, you could use `dayOfMonth = Format(Day(dob), "00")` to get leading zeros (Declare `dayOfMonth` and the others as strings or you will lose them again!)

```
Dim dayOfMonth As String 
'...
Dim yearSoc As String 

dayOfMonth = Format(Day(dob), "00")
'...
yearSoc = Right(CStr(Year(dob)))  'CStr wouldn't be necessary but this way it's more obvious what is happening.
```

Finally, your function should probably return a boolean instead of a string.